# Transfering MATIC tokens on matic network

Tags: tokens, abi, raw-transaction

I'm attempting to transfer MATIC on the matic testnet (mumbai) and submitting the standard ERC20 transfer call (0xa9059cbb) isn't working.  Here's my transaction:

`0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000accountnumberhere00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000071afd498d0000`

When I send this to dummy ERC (0xaeea34b61f7f6c5c49dbea1383c0de496fed859c678772e5e13fdaae4db187f4), it transfers DERC tokens to the recipient.  When I send it to MATIC (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010), it instead shows as a successful transfer of 0 MATIC to the MATIC account, and no transaction or MATIC shows on the recipient account.

Is there a different ABI that I need to be using for transfering MATIC than other ERC20 tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with this problem in the future:

On the mainnet, MATIC acts like an ERC20 token and should be transferred using ERC20 transactions.

On the matic sidechain, MATIC acts like ETH and can be transferred by directly sending a message to the recipient with the MATIC amount in the 'value' field.

Answer (score 0):

Since Polygon is an L2, it doesn't have its own native currency like ETH on mainnet.

MATIC is an ERC20 token to the bone, however it can *act* as a native currency on MetaMask. That's why you see MATIC in MetaMask when the Polygon network is selected.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be how it works on Polygon.
See https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x8eacf309980cec4b7abda5a2135c6a6db4e22471b4a880df8df677417906c0b6 for an example of 0.02 MATIC being sent on Polygon.  As you can see, it took 21000 gas and the data field is blank, so it is a native send, NOT an ERC20 transfer method.